# Rails - Sorting and max of hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

i'm creating a hash as subset to run over table data.

```
  @comparison =[]
    @surrounding_divesites.each do |surr|
      @distance = Text::Levenshtein.distance(surr.name, curr_divesite.name)
      @count_logs = Log.where("divesite_id = ?", surr.id).count
      @comparison.append ( {
        "site_id" => surr.id,
        "distance" => @distance,
        "count" => @count_logs
      })
   end
```

After that I want to sort_by specific values (count, distance) and also find the max value. 
I used several alternative, but up to not unsuccessful. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort:

```rb
  @comparison.sort_by{|c| c["distance"] }
```

max:

```rb
  @comparison.max_by{|c| c["count"]}
```